# Table thead fixed and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [website](http://develop.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wohnungen.html) and I'm trying to fix the thead of the table on Internet Explorer (all versions if it is possible).

On Chrome, Safari and Firefox it works.

To fix it I'm using this JS script:

```
document.getElementById("wrap").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});
```

...but does not works. I've also tried with this:

```
this.querySelector("thead").style['msTransform'] = translate;
```

...with no results.

How can I solve it?